# How to know which rights my roles on a discord server have?

Tags: discord

For example, how do I know if my @everyone or @here in a discord channel is actually annoying people, even if the server doesn't have emotes especially designed to be used to express this sort of discontent?

Or any of the other rights you can assign to certain roles in the "Roles" management tab inside the "Server Settings" of a server without being the admin and being able to open these settings?

Also, from the flip side, how can I acquire which roles may be eligible for a certain action I want to take on a server, for example joining a channel, without being a moderator with insights into the management system?

Comment: `@everyone` and `@here` are global so yeah it's annoying people if overused

Answer (score 1):

- **`@here`** notifies all non-idle users currently online
- **`@everyone`** notifies all users, even if they are offline

...both are global by default so yeah it's annoying people if overused. Server owners can enable or disable the option for specific user roles in their server settings. To set permissions on a server:

- click the small arrow next to the server name.

  [image: 0]
- open **Server Settings**
- go to **Roles**
- then click a role to customize that role's permissions

  [image: 0]

---

> ### Mentioning roles
>
> When mentioning a role, every user that has access to the channel will
>   get a notification and the channel will be highlighted as if mentioned
>   directly. To allow a role to be mentioned by anyone, enable it for
>   that role under **Server settings > Roles > Allow anyone to @mention
>   this role**. Many server owners like to enable this for a short time
>   when wanting to mention all users of a role once and then disable it
>   again when making announcements to a specific role.
>
> **https://discordia.me/mentions**

---

**[And this is how to stop `@everyone` notifications.](https://support.discordapp.com/hc/en-us/articles/215253148-How-do-I-stop-everyone-mentions-from-select-servers-)**

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't sure a user actually could view their Roles on a server, but I found it in Discord's user list.

1. Go to the user list (It should be visible on the right hand side of the application and opened by default. Click the Users icon (hover text is "Members List") next to search to open it.
2. Find your username.
3. Right click.
4. Go down to the Roles submenu at the bottom.

**Note: The roles displayed looked like self-identified roles only.** If the server has other roles and they have selected the option for "Display role members separately from online members", you can check the Member List for your main role. You can always assume your just an "everyone", but if you're not, then there doesn't seem to be any way to find those hidden roles. This is probably because **Moderators might need hidden roles to keep track of antisocial behavior.** You also might be able to ask the Moderator Bot what your roles are.

[image: Discord's user list right-click menu]